# R - Reshaping repeated row value into column

Tags: r, reshape, data-science, tidyverse

I have data like this:

```
Name     Rating
Tom      3
Tom      4
Tom      2
Johnson  5  
Johnson  7
```

But I'd like it so each unique name is instead a column, with the ratings below, in each row. How can I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this does the job but introduces some NAs.
Edit: Replace the NAs with some other Rating.

```
 mydata<-data.frame(Name=c("Tom","Tom","Tom","Johnson","Johnson"),Rating=c(3,4,2,5,7))
    library(reshape2)
    library(tidyverse)



mydata1<-mydata %>% 
  mutate(Name=as.factor(Name)) %>% 
melt(id.var="Name") %>% 
  dcast(variable+value~Name) %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  rename(Name=variable) %>%
 select_if(is.numeric) 
mydata1 %>% 
  mutate(Johnson=as.factor(Johnson),Tom=as.factor(Tom)) %>% 
  mutate(Johnson=fct_explicit_na(Johnson,na_level = "No Rating"),
         Tom=fct_explicit_na(Tom,na_level = "No Rating"))

 Johnson       Tom
1 No Rating         2
2 No Rating         3
3 No Rating         4
4         5 No Rating
5         7 No Rating
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way of doing it

```
x <- data.frame(c("Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Johnson", "Johnson"), c(3,4,2,5,7))
colnames(x) <- c("Name", "Rating")
n <- unique(x[,1])
m <- max(table(x[,1]))
c <- data.frame(matrix(, ncol = length(n), nrow = m))
for (i in 1:length(n)) {
  l <- x[which(x[,1] == n[i]), 2]
  l2 <- rep("", m - length(l))
  c[,i] <- c(l, l2)
}
colnames(c) <- n
```

Results:

```
  Tom Johnson
1   3       5
2   4       7
3   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using CRAN package `reshape`.

```
library(reshape2)

d <- dcast(mydata, Rating ~ Name, value.var = "Rating")[-1]
d
#  Johnson Tom
#1      NA   2
#2      NA   3
#3      NA   4
#4       5  NA
#5       7  NA
```

As you can see, there are too many `NA` values in this result. One way of getting rid of them could be:

```
d <- lapply(d, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
n <- max(sapply(d, length))
d <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(d, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, n - length(x)))))

d
#  Johnson Tom
#1       5   2
#2       7   3
#3      NA   4
```